# Does boost::any / std::any store small objects in-place?

Tags: c++, boost, c++17

To hold arbitrarily large objects, `boost::any` / `std::any` surely needs to allocate heap space for objects. However, for small types whose size is less or equal to a pointer (`int,char,bool,...`), `any` could instead store the value in-place in the pointer slot or in some other in-place memory and not allocate heap space. But does the implementation do this?

I have a scenario where I often store small types in an `any` and only sometimes larger types like `string`s. The code is quite hot and therefore I am asking the question. If the optimization is not performed, I might be better off with an own implementation that stores small types in-place.

Comment: "The code is quite hot"? Do you mean it's not performing well? Have you profiled / are you compiling with optimizations? I highly doubt this extra memory access would be your game changer of performance.

Comment: [`libc++` trunk](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/any) has [small object](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/any#L132) optimization for `std::any`. I suspect it should be same for any reasonable STL implementation...

Comment: @mascoj "hot code" is a code portion that is executed significantly more often than the rest, and thus is the most prone to become a bottleneck.

Comment: @mascoj: I am creating / disposing of these objects very often. The allocations/deallocations might slow me down.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no guarantee but the C++17 draft states in [[any.class]](http://eel.is/c++draft/any.class) that

> Implementations should avoid the use of dynamically allocated memory for a small contained object. [ Example: where the object constructed is holding only an int.  — end example ] Such small-object optimization shall only be applied to types `T` for which `is_­nothrow_­move_­constructible_­v<T>` is `true`.

Unfortunately it does not give a recommendation for what should be considered *small* except to say a `int` should be able to be stored in place.

Comment: Would have been nice if the max size could have been specified as a template parameter (with a default value of whatever it is now)

Comment: @NathanOliver Not really. Having a proliferation of `any`s with `any<16>` being a different type from `any<42>` defeats half the purpose of having such vocabulary types.

Comment: @ViktorSehr Certainly it can be implemented like that, I did it. If you indicate a way to contact you I can send you my implementation.
In my view, `std::any` gives you two different capabilities: 1) type erasure (being able to have an object of any arbitrary type), 2) convertibility from any object type to `any` (changing what you used to hold to something of a different type in the same `any`).  If one makes the threshold to not store the value in-place a template argument, you may lose #2, but it is trivial to make a template constructor of other `any`.
I don't see the drawback.

Comment: @T.C. Hadn't thought about that aspect.  It would make it like `std::array` is now.  I can see where that would want to be avoided.  Maybe they could use a different mechanic to specify what you want to consider small.

Comment: So we might have a new `std::any_n` besides `std::any` (the latter might even use the former internally), and it would be up to the user which of the disadvantages he'd prefer to have to cope with...

Comment: @Aconcagua It's possible.  Someone would probably have to propose it.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand the [Boost.Any](https://github.com/boostorg/any/blob/develop/include/boost/any.hpp) source code correctly, and from poking at it in a debugger, it does not apply a small object optimization. (Note the unconditional use of new.)

```
    template<typename ValueType>
    any(const ValueType & value)
      : content(new holder<
            BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME remove_cv<BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME decay<const ValueType>::type>::type
        >(value))
    {
    }
```

Comment: @John - I linked to Boost 1.66 or so; see https://github.com/boostorg/any/blob/boost-1.66.0/include/boost/any.hpp

Answer (score 4):

Nathan Oliver's and Josh's Kelley's answers are correct:  There is no guarantee, boost does not use the small value optimization.

In more practical cases,
https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/experimental/any#L129
Shows you libc++ (clang's) gives you 3 void pointers worth of space, (24 bytes if they are 8 bytes wide)

libstdc++ only one pointer:
https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/experimental/any?view=markup#l106

Changing `any` to make the size a template parameter is not difficult, just that you should also make sure there is convertibility between `any` of different sizes.

IMO, the performance difference is so substantial between small size optimization and heap allocated, according to my benchmarks, and the implementation cost of making it a template so small it will become part of the standard

Comment: I don't think it will become a template in the standard, at least not in the C++17 standard. The standard is already feature complete.