# Differences between `boost::any` and `std::any`

Tags: c++, boost, c++17

C++17 introduces the object container [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/any), based on the boost library [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/any.html).
My question is: Is the standardized `any` equivalent to the boost version, or are there differences?

A [similar question has been posted about `variant`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40201371/what-are-the-differences-between-stdvariant-and-boostvariant), and some differences exist in that case, but I could not find references about `any`.

---

EDIT: A difference I could see is the availability of the methods `emplace`. More than a difference in the API I'm interested to the differences between the behavior and the guarantees. For instance, different allocations would be significant for me.

Comment: If memory allocations and indirection are a concern you should not be using `any` at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41878040/does-boostany-stdany-store-small-objects-in-place

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: they are not a concern, but I would like to know what happens in what case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm interested to the differences between the behavior and the guarantees.

There aren't any behavioral differences; not really. They both have the same requirements on the ValueType (copy-constructible, and a destructor that doesn't emit exceptions). They both provide the same operations on the values they store, with pretty much identical exception guarantees.

The principle difference is that `boost::any`'s implementation at present doesn't implement small object optimization, while `std::any` implementations *may* provide it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. An [answer in the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41887519/1900563) says that boost never applies small object optimization. That answer is of year old. Did the boost implementation change I the meantime?

Comment: `boost::any` does not implement small object optimization.

Comment: Thanks for editing the answer. Do standard libraries implement small object optimizations, that you know?